# Designing R loops with coordinate values and generating plots

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, for-loop, coordinates

I have two set sets containing three `x` and `y` coordinate pairs:

DataSet 1 (DS1):

```
1,1:
2,1:
1,2
```

DataSet 2 (DS2):

```
5,5:
5,4:
2,2
```

I want to design a loop that would identify those coordinate pairs in `DS2` within one `x` or `y` unit of any point in `DS1` (for this data set it would only ID `DS2` point (2,2)) and then plot `DS1` and the identified points in `DS2` on the same plot.

Comment: Is there a specific problem you've encountered with your coding? What have you tried thus far?

Comment: my issue is trying to figure out how to have the data run through each set of pairs from DS1.  I can get it to work if this is DS1 (x1=2,y1=2) and DS2 (x2,y2 = 2,1  2,2  5,5  6,5  5,6  3,3) first I eliminate all x2 values that are not within 2 points of x1.      >x2x<-subset(DS2,x2<x1+2 & x2>x1-2,c("x2","y2")).    gives me > x2x
 X Y
 2 1
 2 2
 3 3   then i can find the y values that are with in 2 of y1 by this.    >x2xy<-subset(x2x,y2<y1+2 & y2>y1-2,c("x2","y2")) .  yields > x2xy
 X  Y
 2  1
 2  2
  if I add extra data points to DS1 it messes with it  any suggestions?